# List Sorting does not working with ajax using datatable in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I am using Datatable of jQuery in laravel for viewing the listing with ajax but when am clicking on sorting button then draw parameter increase its value and sort data according to the page.

here I am sharing some code:

My controller:

```
/**
 * listings of organizations table
 * 
 * @param  $request object of Request class
 * @return response json
 */
public function apiListing(Request $request)
{
    $request['page'] = $request['draw'];
    $columns = $request->input('columns');
    $order = $request->input('order');
    $orderField = $columns[$order[0]['column']]['data'];
    $orderDir = $order[0]['dir'];
    $request['s'] = $orderField;
    $request['o'] = $orderDir;
    $request['limit'] = $request->input('length');
    $offset = $request->input('start');
    $request['page'] = $offset < $request['limit'] ? 1 : intval($offset/$request['limit'])+1;
    $utilities = $this->service->paginate($request);
    $totalFiltered = $utilities->total();
    $data = [];

    foreach ($utilities as $key => $utility) {
        $data[] = [
            'utility_id'        => $utility->utility_id,
            'name'              => $utility->name,
            'street_address'    => $utility->street_address,
            'city'              => $utility->city,
            'state_code'        => $utility->state_code,
            'zip'               => $utility->zip,
        ];
    }

    $json_data = array(
                "draw"            => intval($request->input('draw')),
                "recordsTotal"    => intval($totalFiltered),
                "recordsFiltered" => intval($totalFiltered),
                "data"            => $data   
                );

    return response()->json($json_data);
}
```

my javascript:

```
function getUtilitiesListingObj()
{
    return new function() {
        this.$tableObj = $('.utilities-listing-table'),
        this.$searchForm = $('#utilitiesSearch'),
        this.$datatableObj = '',
        this.bind = function() {
            var $obj = this;
            $obj.filtering();
            $obj.initiallizeDataTable();
        },
        this.initiallizeDataTable = function() {
            var $obj = this;
            $.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oStdClasses, {
                "sFilterInput": "form-control",
                "sLengthSelect": "form-control"
            });

            $obj.$dataTableObj = $obj.$tableObj.DataTable( {
                "pageLength": 100,
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, 100, 500], [10, 25, 50, 100, 500]], 
                "order": [[ 1, "asc" ]],
                "stateSave": true,
                "scrollY": "500px",
                "serverSide": true,
                "processing": true,
                "oLanguage": {
                   "sProcessing": "<span>Loading utilities...<span>",
                   "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_"
                },
                "fnDrawCallback": function(o) {
                    $('.dataTables_scrollBody').scrollTop(0);
                },
                "initComplete": function(settings, json) {

                    $('table.utilities-listing-table thead th, table.utilities-listing-table thead td').each(function () {
                       var $td = $(this);
                       $td.attr('title', $td.text());
                    });

                    /* Apply the tooltips */
                    $('table.utilities-listing-table thead th, table.utilities-listing-table thead td').tooltip(
                    {
                       "container": 'body'
                    }); 
                },
                "ajax":{
                        "url": GLOBAL_SETTINGS.UTILITIES_LISTING_URL,
                        "dataType": "json",
                        "type": "get",
                        "data": function(d) {
                            d.name = $('.name-filter').attr('value');
                            d.street_address = $('.address-filter').attr('value');
                            d.city = $('.city-filter').attr('value');
                            d.state = $('.state-filter').attr('value');
                            d.zip = $('.zip-filter').attr('value');
                        }
                },
                "columns": [
                    { "data": "utility_id", "width": "10%" },
                    { "data": "name", "width": "30%" },
                    { "data": "street_address", "width": "20%"},
                    { "data": "city", "width": "10%"},
                    { "data": "state_code", "width": "10%"},
                    { "data": "zip", "width": "10%"},
                ]
            });

        },
        this.filtering = function() {
            var $obj = this;
            $('div.box-body').on('submit', 'form#utilitiesSearch', function() {
                var $form =$(this);
                var $nameObj = $('.name-filter');
                var $addressObj = $('.address-filter');
                var $cityObj = $('.city-filter');
                var $stateObj = $('.state-filter');
                var $zipObj = $('.zip-filter');

                $nameObj.attr('value', $nameObj.val());
                $addressObj.attr('value', $addressObj.val());
                $cityObj.attr('value', $cityObj.val());
                $stateObj.attr('value', $stateObj.val());
                $zipObj.attr('value', $zipObj.val());

                $obj.$dataTableObj.rows().invalidate().draw();
                // $("input[id=hidden_field_name]").val($nameObj.val());
             //    $("input[id=hidden_field_cid]").val($cidObj.val());
                // $("input[id=hidden_field_only_seller_buyer]").val($onlySellerFilerFilter.val());
                return false;
            });
        }
    }
}
```

When I am clicking on sorting button then it does not sort data and draw parameter increase its value like this:
[image]

Comment: You are passing correct data to `$this->service->paginate($request)` but it's unclear what this method does. It is also expected behavior for DataTables 1.10.x that `draw` value increments with each request.